# How to display last updated record for multiple records

Tags: sql

I have joined two tables to pull the data I need. I'm having trouble only displaying the most current record from one table. What I'm trying to do is look for the last updated value. I have tried to incorporate max() and row_num but have not had any success.

Here is what I currently have:

```
select distinct t1.CaId,t1.Enrolled,t1.Plan,t2.Category,t2.updateddate
from table.one(nolock) t1 
inner join table.two(nolock) t2 on t1.CaId=t2.CaID 
where t1.coverageyear=2016
and right(t1.Plan,2)<>left(t2.Category,2)
order by 5 desc
```

Comment: Would be helpfull if you can show the what columns the tables have.

Comment: Which table has all the changed data?

Comment: Pls post your schemas,input and output

Comment: The table 2 has the updated values. Tables 1 and 2 share CaId the Enrolled and plan are only in table 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can join your main query with a subquery that just grabs the last update date for each ID, like this:

```
select all_rec.CaId, all_rec.Enrolled, all_rec.[Plan], all_rec.Category, all_rec.updateddate
from
    (select distinct t1.CaId,t1.Enrolled,t1.[Plan],t2.Category,t2.updateddate
    from [table.one](nolock) t1 
    inner join [table.two](nolock) t2 on t1.CaId=t2.CaID 
    where t1.coverageyear=2016
    and right(t1.[Plan],2)<>left(t2.Category,2)
    ) as all_rec
inner join
    (SELECT max(updateddate) AS LAST_DATE, CaId 
        FROM [table.two](nolock) 
        GROUP BY CaId) 
        AS GRAB_DATE 
on (all_rec.Ca_Id = GRAB_DATE.Ca_Id)
and (all_rec.updateddate = GRAB_DATE.updateddate)
order by 5 desc
```

I added brackets around your usages of `table` and `Plan` because those are SQL reserved words.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get *last updated value*, then just simply add to your query:

```
order by t2.updateddate desc
```

It will show *most current record* from tables.